# Print out result alongside the column that produced the output

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compute the least square error between a train dataset (x,y) with a supposed line of best fit data set (y1, y2,y3,y4....y50). I want to know which of these ideal function is the best. My entire code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import operator

class Stats:
    def __init__(self,X,y,model):
        self.data = X
        self.target = y
        self.model = model
    
    def sse(self):
        """ Return sum of squared errors(model vs actual)"""
        squared_errors = (self.target - self.model) ** 2
        return round(np.sum(squared_errors),2)

def pretty_print(stats_obj):
    item = (("sse:",column,stats_obj.sse()))
    return item

def iterate(y):
    results = []
    X = training_data.iloc[:,0]
    model = ideal_function_data.iloc[:,1:]
    col = model.columns.values
    for column in col:
        stats = Stats(X, y, model[column])
        dump = pretty_print(stats)
        results.append(dump)
    function = min(results, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
    return results

y = training_data.iloc[:,1]
result = iterate(y)
```

The expected result should be `('sse:', 'y47', 34.03)`. The result works outside the function, but gives a `NameError: name 'column' is not defined`inside the function.

Comment: Add one additional argument to ```pretty_print``` function (e.g., ```pretty_print(stats_obj, column)```), and then call it by ```pretty_print(stats, column)```.

Comment: You are awesome @HenryTjhia. Thanks it worked.